# Google Earth Is Not Working

Tags: 12.04, google-earth

I am using ubuntu 12.04 lts and i want to install google earth so I went onto it's official site and downloaded the 64bit.deb package. When i typed:

```
sudo apt-get install google-earth-stable
```

In the terminal, everything went alright and it opened too, but the fly-to feature wont work. So I asked it on `askubuntu.com` and here is the link to it: [How Do I Search In Google Earth?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/427593/how-do-i-search-in-google-earth)

I did what it said and it fixed it. but I cannot even open google earth after I shut it down. What can I do to make it work.

Comment: Try to follow [this answer](http://askubuntu.com/a/430352/163331) for the 32 bit Google earth.

Comment: try to open google earth from the command line with sudo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To be sincere I haven't used Google Earth for a while but after I repeat some steps that you've done I experienced some issues with version 6 too. I'm also running 12.04 and this what I did to fix this:

Remove everything that belongs to Google Earth currently installed, I advise you to use [Synaptic](https://askubuntu.com/questions/131979/how-to-install-synaptic-package-manager) open it and type `Google Earth` click on marked item area and from pop up menu choose `complete removal` after it removed close Synaptic.

Now open a terminal <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> and run:

```
sudo apt-get update

sudo apt-get upgrade

sudo apt-get autoremove
```

(let it to remove listed packages)

Now go to your `/home` press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd> find folders `.cache` and `.config` search for Google Earth in them and delete everything, for now we're done.

Go back to terminal and install `gdebi`:

```
sudo apt-get install gdebi
```

Ok, now download [Google Earth](http://www.google.com/earth/download/ge/agree.html) 7`.deb` file, when download is done, type in terminal:

```
sudo gdebi /home/yourname/Downloads/packagename.deb
```

hit <kbd>Enter</kbd> then type `y` and hit <kbd>Enter</kbd> again.

or go manually to a downloaded file directory and on a file mouse right click and choose install with `gdebi` in opened window click `install package` and agree to whatever comes out. Done.

When installation has been completed reboot the system, for some reasons I also experienced loading issues with Google Earth to start, so after a clean restart everything works perfectly fine, I closed it and opened it twice, it starts without problems and the search bar works too.

This workout works on 12.04 perfectly, so good luck!